# A function problem

Tags: calculus, functions, systems-of-equations

Let the solution set of the equation:

$\sqrt{\left[x+[\frac{x}{2}]\right]}+\left[[\sqrt{x}]+[\frac{x}{3}]\right]=3 $ be $[a,b)$.

find $a\cdot b$, Where $[.]$ Is greatest integer function and $\{.\}$ Is fractional part function.

Comment: is this what you meant?

Comment: could you show your attempt of solving the question?

Comment: I approached like made cases when x is an integer and when x is not and integer. Further when x is a multiple of 2  or 3 but that doesn't seem to be fruitful to me

Comment: Can you now solve or tell us your approach that would be helpful?

Comment: @Jneven, the fractional part function no longer appears anywhere in the equation.

Comment: what part is the fractional part

Comment: Square rooted x is in fractional part function

Comment: Actually there is mistake it is √{x}  with no gif on this one . Someone edit it.

Comment: @Jneven, if you look carefully at the original version of the question in the edit history, you'll see there was a $\{x\}$ inside the second square root.

Comment: @Barry Cipra try the problem and your approach. Did you get what I said?

Comment: @Jneven re-edit it.

Comment: @SMSheik here $\sqrt{\{x\}}$ is useless..

Comment: There is no $\{\}$ in the equation. This is suspect.

Comment: @YvesDaoust in one of the comments OP has pointed out the correction... I made that correction, but my edit got rejected :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice carefully in the equation, $$\sqrt{\left[x+[\frac{x}{2}]\right]}+\left[\sqrt{\{x\}}+[\frac{x}{3}]\right] = 3$$, this $\sqrt{\{x\}}$ is useless. So question becomes $$\sqrt{\left[x+[\frac{x}{2}]\right]} + \left[\frac{x}{3}\right] = 3$$.

It's quite clear that it won't have any solution in $[0, 3)$, it clearly satisfies for $[3, 4)$. I don't know how to explain it more. So, answer should be $3\cdot 4 = 12$.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Zenix' solution (read it first):

The way to start is to note that the second term on the left is an integer, so the first must be as well.  Both are nonnegative, so they must be in $\{0,1,2,3\}$.  Neither can be $3$ while the other is $0$, so one must be $1$ and the other must be $2$.  If the second term is $2$, the first will be at least $2$, so $x \in [3,6)$ with
$$\sqrt{\left[x+[\frac{x}{2}]\right]}=2\\ \left[\frac{x}{3}\right] = 1\\
\left[x+[\frac{x}{2}]\right]=4$$
which finally gives $x \in [3,4)$

Comment: How did you conclude second one is non negative?

Comment: Because if $x \lt 0$ the argument of the square root will be negative.  If$x \ge 0$ the second is nonnegative.